# Trying to pass in a boolean C# variable to a javascript variable and set it to true

Tags: c#, javascript

Having issues where in my .aspx page I pass in a boolean variable (C#) to a javascript function that is expecting a boolean type.

BUt the C# variable returns True, and javascript doesn't like the uppercase.

```
myjavascript( <%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp %> );
```

If I convert the c# variable to string, then my javascript variable becomes a string and not a js bool value!

what is the solution to this nightmare? lol

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this:

```
myjavascript( <%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp.ToString().ToLower() %> );
```

Comment: It's funny that we must do a so not functional conversion to transform a simple type like boolean but it works! Thanx

Comment: Wow, how stupid.  Having to turn a boolean to a string and then making it lower to compare it to a javascript boolean.  It works though.  Thanks!

Comment: worked without <%= %> syntax for me but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 27):

if you need to do this often, just add this to the top of the javascript (or your js library file, etc.)

```
var True = true, False = false;
```

Then you code

```
myjavascript( <%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp %> );
```

Would work just fine.

Another option if for whatever reason you don't want to use the variables is to write your javascript call like this:

```
myjavascript( '<%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp %>'=='True' );
```

Comment: Good idea, although this will end up on the page as `myjavascript('True' == 'True')`, which doesn't require the use of variables. If you had `myjavascript(<%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp %> == 'True')` in mind, the variables are required but it will never evaluate to `true`. Another idea based on yours: `myjavascript('<%= MyBooleanVariableInCSharp %>' === '<%= bool.TrueString %>')`.

Comment: @Wynand I edited my answer to clarify that I was offering two separate options

Answer (score 11):

You could also do this.

```
myjavascript(<%=myBooleanVariableInCSharp ? "true" : "false" %>);
```

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are targeting the old version, before **Razor** 
if you are using **Razor** then this is the solution

```
myjavascript( @MyBooleanVariableInCSharp.ToString().ToLower() );
```

Comment: `var myBoolInJavaScript = @Model.MyBoolInCSharp.ToString().ToLower();` worked like intended. Thank you for this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
function toBool(s){ 
   return s==="True";
}

var b = toBool("@csharpvariable.ToBoolean()");
```