# How to map bool from C# to a boolean variable in JScript? The automatic conversion converts a boolean true into a string "True"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am implementing IClientValidatable in an ASP.Net MVC 5 with VS2019. The following portion of code creates the validation rule, the line `rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mustbeeven", this.mEven);` creates the paramenter which must be of type boolean but is is passed as string.

```
public partial class EvenOrOddNumberAttribute : IClientValidatable
    {       
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();         
            rule.ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mustbeeven", this.mEven); //mEven is a field of type bool
            rule.ValidationType = "evenoroddnumber";
            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

and the corresponding javascript code which validates the rule in the client side. The line of code `if (mustbeeven == true)` is false because it value is "True" (string) when in previous C# code `this.mEven == true` (boolean) and "False" when `this.mEven == false`:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />  
//var True = true, False = false;
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("evenoroddnumber", "mustbeeven");
$.validator.addMethod("evenoroddnumber", function (value, element, mustbeeven) {
    if (value) {
        if (mustbeeven == true) //Here mustbeeven equals "True"!
        { 
            return (value % 2 == 0);
        }
        else {
            return (value % 2 != 0);
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

There is a similar old question about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656715/trying-to-pass-in-a-boolean-c-sharp-variable-to-a-javascript-variable-and-set-it) that patches the problem in someway but I'm looking for a better solution, if possible, having the parameter of type boolean in the Javasript side.

Comment: Why not simply compare strings: `if (mustbeeven === 'True')`? I guess that parameters always serialized as strings so there is no way around.

Comment: Are you sure it is always serialized as strings? I'm not an expert in javascript, on the contrary, but it would be nice to be able to add the the value to the adaptar as boolean. Something like ```$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("evenoroddnumber", "mustbeeven"**[, "boolean"]**);```

Answer (score 0):

instead of (mustbeeven == true) use (mustbeeven == "True")

Comment: Yes... but it would be better if I can compare booleans because it is the well known type of the field at the server side.

Comment: @Lupa The server side type doesn't matter. These parameter values are just rendered as html attributes so obviously they are just strings on the client side. You can inspect your html and you should see something like `data-val-evenoroddnumber-mustbeeven="True"`

Comment: It is preferable for me to compare booleans. I do not like to compare string and even less to search for tags or ids in the html to finally compare case-sensitive strings because It is error prone and less intuitive.